# How to extract a part of a string and click on it using Appium inspector

Tags: android, testing, xpath, automation, appium

I am working on an Android app. my app has a Text "This is for the reference. to see the full list, click here".

I need to some how click on the text : "click here" so that I can do automation testing. clicking on the text "Click here" will take me to a webpage. so I can validate this journey once I figure out how to click on the text.

I am using Appium inspector to get the xpath and all. but still I couldn't figure out how to click on this text.

Answer (score 0):

Consider utilizing the "Click Text" keyword.

```
Click Text    Click here
```

Referring to the [documentation quoted below](https://robocorp.com/docs/libraries/3rd-party-libraries/appium/keywords#click-text), this keyword has the capability to click on a specific fragment of text within a paragraph by default :

> Click Text(text, exact_match=False)
>
> Click text identified by text.
>
> By default tries to click first text involves given text, if you would
> like to click exactly matching text, then set exact_match to True.